# Using git in Windows, does the --shared option to git-init do anything useful?

Tags: windows, git

I noticed that when using the Git Extensions on Windows to `init` a bare repository that it does

```
git init --bare --shared=all
```

I've read the manual for the `--shared` options. It seems a convenience to set folder permissions but the descriptions are very UNIX-y (e.g. `umask`).

My remote repositories *are* going to be shared, but they're on a remote UNC share under Windows Authentication.

So, in my situation, is there any need for this `--shared` option, for instance if I was initialising a repo from the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except from the permissions (that indeed might not work in windows), using the `--shared` flag also sets the [`receive.denyNonFastForwards`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html) config in shared repositories. Of course you could also set that manually if you want to...

Try running `git init --bare --shared=all` from a `git-bash` shell, and see if you get any reports regarding permissions.

Comment: Running that from `git-bash`, I got no reports regarding permissions. Checking the config file, you are correct about `receive.denyNonFastForwards`. The property `core.sharedrepository` is also set. Apart from that I will assume there is no real point to this switch on Windows and mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: @PeterReavy Just out of curiosity, (because I haven't tried it on windows) have you noticed and changes in the direcory's permissions after creating the shared repo?

Comment: I made one repo of each on my local file system and ran `cacls` against both and diffed the output. It made no difference to the permissions at all.