# Git find first non-local commit

Tags: git, git-rev-parse

Related: [List Git commits not pushed to the origin yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080509/list-git-commits-not-pushed-to-the-origin-yet)

`git rev-parse HEAD` gives me the latest commit in the workspace, but this can be a locally committed githash. In other words, a commit which is not pushed to remote yet

how do I find the latest commit which also exists in remote in the workspace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the latest commit on the currently checked out branch's configured remote branch, do

```
# first get your remote-tracking branches up-to-date with remote
git fetch

# then do
git rev-parse @{upstream}
# or even just
git rev-parse @{u}
```

*(Note : `@{upstream} / @{u}` are **not** placeholders, they're meant to be typed as is)*

From the [doc](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) :

> **[<branchname>]@{upstream}, e.g. master@{upstream}, @{u}**
> The suffix @{upstream} to a branchname (short form @{u}) refers to the branch that the branch specified by branchname is set to build on top of (configured with branch..remote and branch..merge). A missing branchname defaults to the current one.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, `git rev-parse HEAD` gives you the hash ID of the *current* commit.  That's not necessarily the *latest*, and it need not match what is in the working tree even in normal use (because the working tree can be modified and not yet committed).  These points interfere with answering your question as asked, too: perhaps you don't want the *latest* commit.  Moreover, the commit(s) in some remote repository to which you can `git push` are usually not in *any* working tree, because such remote repositories are normally *bare* repositories: [bare repositories generally accept `git push` requests, and non-bare ones don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68537099/1256452).

All that aside, what you *probably* want is a simple:

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

or:

```
git rev-parse origin/<some-other-name-here>
```

or:

```
git rev-parse @{upstream}
```

The last one of these needs further explanation.  The first two simply use your existing names, in your existing Git repository, to find a hash ID, in the same sort of way that `git rev-parse HEAD` does—though usually *less* complicated.

It's possible that your local Git repository is *out of date* with respect to the other (remote) Git repository.  In that case, you might need to run:

```
git fetch origin
```

first in order to obtain any new commits that they have, and update your various *remote-tracking names:* the names like `origin/master` and `origin/develop` and so on.

#### What's going on here

Git defines a *branch name* as a name—like `master` or `main`, or `develop`, or `feature/tall` or whatever—that holds the hash ID of some existing, valid commit in this repository.<sup>1</sup>  That hash ID, by definition, is the *last* commit "on" that branch.

What Git does with this is itself a little complicated, but if we note that most commits—all the *ordinary* ones<sup>2</sup>—store exactly *one* hash ID for their immediate *parent* commit, we find that we can place commits next to each other, like pearls or beads on a string:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ...
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash ID of some existing commit.  That commit stores the hash ID of its parent (earlier) commit, `G`.  Commit `G` in turn stores the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

Because commits can't be changed, and hash IDs are unpredictable,<sup>3</sup> these arrows always point backwards.  A *branch name* then just points to the last commit in the chain:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Moreover, Git sets things up so that when you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select some branch name as the *current branch*, the special name `HEAD` is *attached to* the branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

At this point, both `git rev-parse main` and `git rev-parse HEAD` will produce the *same hash ID*, namely that of commit `H`.

Should you add a *new* commit, Git constructs the new commit by writing out the snapshot and metadata for that commit and making the metadata include `H`'s hash ID, so that new commit `I` points backwards to existing commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   ...
         \
          I
```

and then, as the *last* step of `git commit`, Git writes the *new commit's hash ID into whichever name `HEAD` is attached to*, giving:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` is still attached to the name `main`, but the name `main` now says that commit `I` is the *last* commit on the branch.

Git does, however, have a mode it calls *detached HEAD* mode.  Here, we tell Git to select some commit by something other than a branch name.  For instance, we might wish to look at commit `G`'s snapshot, and hence run `git checkout hash-of-G` or similar.  The result is:

```
...--G   <-- HEAD
      \
       H--I   <-- main
```

The `git rev-parse HEAD` command now shows the hash ID of commit `G`: not that of commit `H`, not that of commit `I`, but that of commit `H`.  That's because `HEAD` is no longer *attached* (to a branch name), but rather *detached* (meaning `HEAD` contains the hash ID of the commit directly).

(To get back to commit `I` and on branch `main`, we'd use `git checkout main` or `git switch main`.  These will re-attach `HEAD`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you have a damaged repository, there's no such thing as an existing but invalid commit.  The idea here is to emphasize that, although hash IDs *look* like random garbage, you're not allowed to just make one up.  They are in fact [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representations of large numbers produced by running cryptographic checksums, so they're not random at all.

<sup>2</sup>The definition of *ordinary commit* here is that it stores one parent hash ID.  The definition of *merge commit* is a commit that stores two or more parent hash IDs, and Git has a third kind of commit, a *root commit*, that stores *no* parent hash ID.  The root commit—there's always at least one in a non-empty, non-shallow repository—is normally the very first commit someone made for that repository.  It's possible to make more root commits—by mistake or on purpose—but there's rarely a *good* reason to do that; it just falls out of the graph algorithms Git uses.

<sup>3</sup>To make it work like this, Git sticks something unique into each commit.  In particular, each commit has a time-stamp, and in normal use it's too difficult to predict what the *future* time-stamp of some *future* commit would be.  There are some theoretical means to cause problems here but they're impractical even for use as practical jokes, at least today.

---

#### Updating names, including with `git push`

*Branch* names are specific to *each Git repository*.  Your Git repository holds *your* branch names.  Some other Git repository has *its own* branch names.

When you create a branch name, you simply pick some existing commit for it:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

might become:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

You've created the new name `develop` and picked existing commit `H` for that name.  If you now make a new commit `I`, the result includes changing the hash ID stored in `develop`, to produce:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note how, this time, it was the name `develop` that moved, because `HEAD` was attached to `develop`, not to `main`.

Anyone with direct access to a repository can, at any time, create or destroy branch names whenever they like, using `git branch` (perhaps with `-D` to delete), or `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c`.  They can also create new *commits* at any time.

Every commit gets a *unique* hash ID, though.  Once you've created some set of commits, you can then use `git push` to *send* those commits to some other Git.  They get the entire commits—the full snapshot and metadata for each commit—exactly as is, and they compute the same cryptographic checksum, so they assign these identical commits the same hash IDs that your Git assigns them.

By using this principle, the two Gits actually manage to figure out who has which commits by looking *only at the hash IDs*.  This is what enables the distributed nature of a Git repository.  The magic is really all in the hashing.

But there's a problem.  Just as your own Git finds your *latest* commit using some branch name, their Git finds *their* latest commit using *their* branch name(s).  So if you're going to send commit `I` to some other Git repository, over at `origin`, with:

```
git push origin develop
```

from your end, *they* are going to have to set some branch name(s) in *their* repository.  By convention—[because humans are so easily fooled](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/62271644/stupid-humans.jpg)—we tend to want to use the *same branch names* in their repository and in our repository.  So the `git push` above asks them to set *their* `develop`.

That's fine if `develop` is a *new* name.  It's also OK for us to ask them to set their `main`, if we're not going to *lose any of their commits*.  That is, suppose they have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We can ask them to set their `main` to point to some new commit `J`, as long as `J` points back to `H` eventually (probably through `I`):

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- request: please make "main" go here
```

Git calls this kind of request a *fast-forward operation* and generally permits it.  (Many add-on sites like GitHub add fancier branch protection systems that let you be pickier; this fast-forward check is all that's built into base Git though.)  What base Git *won't* let you do is something like this:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- main
         \
          J   <-- request: please make "main" go here
```

because if *they* do that, *they* will lose access to their commit `I`.

#### Remote-tracking names and `git fetch`

To fix this kind of problem, we're supposed to use `git fetch` first, before we run `git push`.  When we run `git fetch`, our Git calls up their Git—as if for `git push`, where we'd send them our new commits—but instead of *sending* commits *to* them, we have our Git ask their Git for any *new-to-us* commits.  They send these over—along with the information about which of their branch names point to which commits—and our Git now has any new commits *they* have, that *we* don't.

Let's assume we both had `...-G-H` on our `main`, and *they* have acquired some new commit `I` from somewhere.  Meanwhile, though, we added a new commit `J` *on our `main`.  So we both started out the same:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

but since then, *they* added `I`:

```
          I   <-- (main in their Git)
         /
...--G--H
```

and we added `J`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- main (in our Git)
```

When we run `git fetch`, we pick up their new commit:

```
          I   <-- (main in their Git)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- main
```

**Our Git can't update our `main` because if it did, we'd lose our own commit `J`.**  So what our Git does—regardless of whether they have added any *new* commits—is to take their *branch* name, `main`, and *change* it.  Our Git turns their *branch* name into a *remote-tracking name* by sticking `origin/` in front of it.<sup>4</sup>  So we end up with this:

```
          I   <-- origin/main
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- main
```

(note: add `HEAD` to our `main` if we have that as our current checked-out branch).

This `git fetch` step:

- gets any new commits they have;
- updates all of our *remote-tracking* names; and thus
- prepares us to do anything necessary to join up new lines of commits (rebase or merge).

This means it's often sensible to follow up a `git fetch` with either a `git rebase` or a `git merge`.  Git offers a convenience command, `git pull`, that combines the two operations.  I dislike it, for many various reasons, and encourage those new to Git to use separate `fetch` and second-Git-command sequences at least until they're quite familiar with the entire process.<sup>5</sup>

In any case, the summary of all of this is that **a remote-tracking name is Git's way of remembering what some other Git repository had in its branch name(s), the last time our Git talked with their Git.**  The `git fetch` operation tends to update all of them, and the `git push` operation updates *one* when it succeeds in doing a push to one branch.  Our Git gets confirmation from their Git that they accepted our request, so our Git now knows that their Git has that name set to that hash ID.<sup>6</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the remote-tracking names are in a separate [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), so even if we accidentally call a (local) branch `origin/xyz`, Git will be able to keep straight our `origin/xyz` *branch*, vs our `origin/xyz` remote-tracking name based on their `xyz` branch.  But this goes back to Stupid Human Tricks, which make Bender the robot laugh; don't do that.

<sup>5</sup>Not everyone is so chary of `git pull`.  Some of my dislike for it is because it had some really bad bugs in it, early on, and I lost a lot of work to `git pull` more than once.  But the main problem is that it does too much, in my opinion.  There's a movement afoot to make `git pull` behave better by default, although I'm not sure how likely this is to happen any time soon.  If and when it does happen, I'll still recommend separate steps, but won't be as quick to suggest that newbies *avoid* `git pull`: it will be a command that, if it works, it did the right thing, and if not, there was no single right thing.

<sup>6</sup>Some of the automatic fetch-time updates were new in Git 1.8.4, so if you have a really ancient Git, older than this, be sure to use `git fetch origin` with no constraints to update everything.  The `git fetch` that `git pull` runs often fails to update anything at all (another reason to be wary of `git fetch`), in these ancient Git versions.

---

#### Branches, upstreams, and `@{upstream}`

Each branch name is allowed, but not required, to have one (1) *upstream* setting.  Typically, the upstream setting of a branch like `main` or `develop` is set to `origin/main` or `origin/develop`: the *remote-tracking name* in your own Git repository.

Having this set enables some convenience items.  It's never actually *required*.  And, when you create an entirely new branch name in your own repository, not using the remote-tracking name (which does not exist yet because the `origin` Git does not have this branch yet), there *isn't* an upstream for it yet and you will want to use `git push -u origin HEAD` or similar to *create* the branch there.  That will create the appropriate remote-tracking name locally, and the `-u` will have your Git set the remote-tracking name as the upstream of the branch.

Once you have set an upstream, the `@{upstream}` suffix—it's technically a suffix that you can append to *any* branch name—tells Git to find that branch's *upstream*.  That is, `master@{upstream}` is `origin/master`, assuming you have set `master`'s upstream to the default `origin/master`.  This repeats for each branch name.

The bare `@{upstream}` text, written just like that, "means" `HEAD@{upstream}`.  So this uses `HEAD` to figure out which branch you're *on*, and then uses the branch's upstream setting to figure out which remote-tracking name to use in your own local Git repository.

All of the above is why and how [RomainValeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554836/1256452) is the short version of this one. :-)