# Find which files conflict before merge?

Tags: git

If we `git pull` and see:

```
git pull
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

then we *can* simply `git pull --merge`<sup>1</sup>to merge the remote into the local and [see the conflicting files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/5783745) with `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`.

But suppose we wish to see which files conflict ***before*** the pull succeeds, that is, ***before*** any merge has occurred.

To be very clear, there's changes on the remote, there's changes on my local, and I want to see what the conflicts are before merging the two.

<sup>1</sup>Sorry, this is wrong, but it's not important. However I'll find the right command and update shortly.

Comment: Short answer is you can't. Your best shot is to try a merge on a throwaway branch. Might be a duplicate of [Is there a git-merge --dry-run option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option) or maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817579/how-can-i-preview-a-merge-in-git).

Comment: @RomainValeri isn't the duplicate previewing a merge between *2 branches* rather than different versions of *the same branch*. I don't see how you could apply the answers in the related question to this scenario, since the answers use `git diff <otherbranch>` but it's the *same* branch.

Comment: @RomainValeri as in, `git diff main` doesn't mean anything if both branches are called `main`.

Comment: @RomainValeri (I'm thinking out loud here) or are you implying to i) *create* a branch, ii) `git pull` and merge the changes, *then* iii) use the strategies in the related question to compare the 2 branches?

Comment: `git diff yourbranch origin/yourbranch` is fine. Even shorter, and branch-name-agnostic : `git diff HEAD @{u}`

Comment: @RomainValeri maybe I didn't make clear in the explanation, but the remote is really "remote" (it's on GitHub). It's not `pull`ed yet, so cannot be `diff`ed.

Comment: @RomainValeri git needs to know about the remote changes. So an answer needs to include how it's going to get them.

Comment: But it can be *fetched*. Fetch from the remote before diffing the remote-tracking ref you just fetched against your local version.

Comment: @RomainValeri when I `fetch` what will the branch be called (if my assumption that it creates a branch is even correct?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241450/discussion-between-romain-valeri-and-stevec).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a complete answer, but based on advice from @RomainValeri and @torek, here's what I attempted:

First, get the remote changes without trying to merge them as pull does:

```
git fetch
```

Now you have the changes on the remote, take a look at them with this:

```
git diff HEAD @{u}
```

(note: ^^ this code came from @RomainValeri, I wish I could say I knew what it does - I can confirm that it works and shows the diff)
*(Edit from Romain : about the `@{u}` expression, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554836/1057485).)*

Then, if and when you're happy, you can merge like so:

```
git merge
```

(note you'll still have to deal with any merge conflicts, but that's another story...)

Comment: To really see what would be a *conflict*, you must find the merge base between HEAD and its upstream: `git merge-base --all HEAD @{u}` for instance. This will get you a raw hash ID (or more than one for the rare case of multiple merge bases). Assuming you get just 1, `git diff <hash> HEAD` shows what you changed, and `git diff <hash> @{u}` shows what they changed. There's a short-cut syntax: `git diff @{u}...HEAD` (note THREE dots here) will find a merge base—hopefully, *the* merge base—and diff that against `HEAD`, and `git diff HEAD...@{u}` will find a merge base and diff that against `@{u}`

Comment: -- and the two diffs will be what you'd get if you ran the two `git diff`s yourself manually. Inspect the set of changed files, and the changes within those changed files, to look for conflicts.

Comment: @torek great to know. Thank you. I am slowing working thorough what each instruction is doing. You're right about the diff not showing the *conflicts* (it only sufficed for me because they were glaring, but in anything other than simple circumstances a git diff probably would not be enough). Also appreciate you showing both the long and shortcut methods.

Answer (score 1):

stevec's answer explains how to *preview* the merge before it occurs, which is a good option.

Another option is to simply perform the merge, and *undo* it if you do not like the conflicts.

To do this, run `git pull` as usual. If there should be a conflict and you do not feel like resolving it right now, you can simply run

`git merge --abort`

(or `git rebase --abort` if you used `git pull --rebase`)

and you will be back to the old state of your working directory. Note that this will only work cleanly if you have *no uncommitted changes* when pulling - but pulling into an unclean working directory is not a good idea anyway, so just commit (or stash) before pulling.